# Create user login programmatically in Drupal 7

Tags: users

The questions is very simple and the task is difficult.
Which functions I need to create a new login form from scratch in Drupal 7?

The reason I need this is because I modified the default login form. It connects to a web service with two different methods and it has different validates, depends from a user roles and lots of customized stuff.

Right now to login as admin, I have to comment my custom module, so I can use the default login form.

I need to create a new login form on different page that will be dedicated to admin user.

Comment: When you say you "modified the default form", do you mean the real one or you just edited a copy, and made it accessible trough a path like "mymodule/login"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going to be possible to list all of the functions involved as your mileage will vary depending on what you need to do.

Basic steps:

1. Read up on and understand the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7); try out a few examples so you're familiar with it.
2. Create a form function in your module, to be delivered in whatever method makes sense (a menu callback or embedding directly, for example). This will involve using [drupal_get_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7), and viewing the [user login form code](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login/7) will be useful here.
3. Create a validate handler for the form which does any validation you need. See [`user_login_default_validators()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_default_validators/7) for the login form defaults.
4. Make use of [`user_login_finalize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_submit/7) in your form's submit handler to log the user in. You'd be best off copying the logic from [`user_login_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_submit/7) almost directly.

Comment: Thank you, Clive for the great answer. I know how to work with Form API, page callbacks, validators and drupal_get_form, so I'm on to the 4th point. I hope this thread will be useful for others that will try to accomplish a custom login form from scratch...thanks again.